# Ejabberd can't connect to users

Tags: ejabberd

I installed ejabberd on my remote server running centos 6.4 and open all ports required. For example I can access the web admin when i go to `http://IP_ADDRES:5280/admin`.

With the following command I added a new user:

```
ejabberdctl register admin localhost password
```

user admin can login at `http://IP_ADDRES:5280/admin` with
username: admin@thelocalhost
password: pass

but now I want to connect to this user with adium. I entered jabber id and password and in the options pane i entered the ip address of the 'connect server'. However adium keeps returning an error: "unable to connect" and I can't find anything in the ejabberd logs. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Had my domain pointing to the wrong ip address of the server.